# Update table row using JQuery with textbox checking and I need to check the textbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

This is my JQuery while button click I append the table row in that table having textbox I need to check that textbox value while focus out please some one help me friends

My html Code friend

```
       <html>
        <head>
         </head>
         <body>
         <table>
           <tr>                
            <td>                    
                <label id="RecFrom">Receied From</label><br />
                <%: Html.TextBox("RecFrom", null, new { @class = "onlyname", id="RFrom" })%>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label id="RecDate" > Received Date </label><br />                    
                <%: Html.TextBox("RecDate", null, new { @class = "date", id="Rdate", @readonly = "readonly" })%>
            </td>
            <td id="External">
                <%: Html.Label("External Referance") %>
                <input type='text' id='Exref' name='ExternalReferance'>
            </td>                    
         </tr>
         <tr id="Refdetails">
            <td>
                <%: Html.Label("Referance Date") %>
                <input type='text' id='RefDate' class='date' readonly='readonly'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.Label("Impact Of Payment") %>
                <select id='Impact' name='Impact' class='dropdown'><option>NO</option><option>YES</option></select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%: Html.Label("Impact By Date") %>
                <input type='text' id='impactdate' name='Impactdate' class='date' readonly='readonly'>
            </td>   

        </tr>
        <tr>   
            <td id="Amountdetails">
                <%: Html.Label("Impact By Amount") %>
                <input type='text' id='Amount' name='ImpactAmount' class='Number'>
            </td>             
        </table>


   <table id="ProductRecipt">
     <tbody>
     <tbody>
    </table>
         <input type="Submit" value="Next" id="btn"/>
   </body>
 </html>
```

My JQuery is

```
     $(document).ready(function ()
         $('#btn').click(function (){
             $('#ProductRecipt tbody').append("<tr><td class='code'>" + ItemCode + "<input type='hidden' name='ItemCode' value='" + ItemCode + "'/></td><td class='desc'>" + $('#Cat').val() + "<input type='hidden' name='ItemName' value='" + $('#Cat').val() + "'/></td><td class='qty'>" + $('#RFrom').val() + "<input type='hidden' name='ReceviedFrom' value='" + $('#RFrom').val() + "'/></td><td class='qty'>" + $('#Rdate').val() + "<input type='hidden' name='ReceviedDate' value='" + $('#Rdate').val() + "'/></td><td>" + result.Quantity + "<input type='hidden' class='TotalQuantity' value= '"+ result.Quantity +"'></td><td><input type='text' class='Rqty' name='ReceviedQuantity'></td><td><input type='text' name='Remarks' style='widht : 75px;'></td><td><input type='button' class='remove' value='remove'/></td></tr>");
           });
       $('#ProductRecipt tbody').on('focusout', '.Rqty', function () {
        var qty = $(this).parent($('#ProductRecipt tbody .TotalQuantity').val());
        alert(qty);
        var rqy = (this).val();
        alert(rqy);
        if (qty > rqy) {
            alert('Enter Minimum Quantity');
            return false;
            $(this).focus();
        }
      });
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that this is what you need:

```
$(document).on("focusout", ".Rqty", function() {
    alert($(this).val());  // do the validation here
});
```

Comment: I having 2 textbox which textbox value is getting

Comment: The one that is focused out.
For example if you click on the textbox and then click out or pres tab or leave the box somehow it will trigger the event.
$(this).val() - represents the value of the text box

Comment: ok then how to compare the value at the same row but another textbox value

Comment: If you have only one field of a given class on the same row you could do something like this:

var the_value_of_the_other_box = $(this).parents('tr').find('.your_class_name').val();
alert(the_value_of_the_other_box);

Comment: You don't need to use the "tbody" selector when operating with tables on jQuery. This should work just fine:
$('#ProductRecipt').append('your_html_code');

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseout', '#ProductRecipt tbody .Rqty', function() {
 var qty = $(this).parent($('.TotalQuantity').val());
    alert(qty);
    var rqy = ('.Rqty').val();
    if (qty > rqy) {
        alert('Enter Minimum Quantity');
        return false;
        $(this).focus();
});
```

Comment: Friend document.body means it can get all table body tags may i right

Comment: I have modified the selector.Please check now

Comment: @Dinesh:would be great if you create some fiddle

Comment: How to Create fiddle friend

Comment: put your code at http://jsfiddle.net/. run and check the output. then save and give the link.

Comment: Ya friend i put it but it does not save and i cannot view the result also

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45103/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-dinesh)